# What is the reason behind the `=>` in a self type?

Tags: scala, self-type

A self type looks like the following example:

```
trait A { self: String => }
```

This says, that trait `A` (or a subtype of it) must inherit the class `String`.

The keyword `self` is followed by `:` analogue to a variable in `var s: String`, where the type comes after `:`.

But what does the `=>` state for in a self type ? What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: It is a weird bit of syntax I think since it seems like an arrow that would be pointing to something...

Comment: Yes, at the beginning of learning Scala, I always thought the arrow is pointing to the rest of the body, looked like a function and was confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Just guess work... You need some specific delimiter of the self-type declaration. Imagine the `=>` was just omitted. `this: String` would be a syntactically valid statement (although the type checker will complain).

So which should be the delimiter? You wouldn't want nested braces like `trait A { self: String { ... }}`. So which non-paired existing delimiters exist? `=>` is the only one that I can think of.

Where is `=>` used elsewhere? As sugar for function types (`A => B`) and for function bodies (`i: Int => i + 1`). Also for call-by-name arguments, and for the cases of a pattern match. This last usage is somewhat coherent with the self-type. It's like matching `this` to be of a particular type, and then defining the body depending on this 'match'. I don't know, maybe this is a silly analogy.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts on that topic. Sounds good to me. I tought into a similar direction.

Answer (score 10):

Note that `self` isn't a keyword, but a normal identifier. You can really write any other valid identifier in place of `self`. And `:` after an expression is a *type ascription*, something entirely valid anywhere an expression is valid.

The `=>` is what tells Scala there is a self-type. Otherwise, `self: Type` looks like a simple statement, an expression. For example:

```
class A
class B extends A {
  this: A
}
```

That is valid Scala code, and it does not have a self type.

Comment: Good point, thank you. Is there a concrete reason for using the `=>` as symbol for a self-type or is it just picked up, because it fits good to the rest of Scalas syntax ?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood Odersky is averse to reserved symbols and keywords, so he tries to reuse the ones he has. I think he went too far with that when it comes to underscores, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is in scope inside the body of a class, so in that sense it is a parameter (though we never think of it that way). The self-type syntax simply makes it explicit, and allows one to give it a different name (and type). So the arrow becomes a very good choice as a separator between the binder and its scope.